# Can I generate table creation sql from Zend_db?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have to work on this project written using Zend Framework. This is a project developed by somebody else that is unreachable at this time and I only have the php code but not the database.

I've never worked with Zend Framework but from what I've managed to understand it's using Zend_db to relate with a MySQL database. Like I said the mysql database is missing so I was wandering if there is any way to generate the SQL needed to create the database and tables based on the models in the PHP code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

You will have to examine the code and reverse engineer it to create the tables/columns that you need for the application to work.

Comment: Voted up, somehow I initially thought he wanted to know how to programmatically create tables.

Comment: I had to create all the tables by hand :/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate tables by hand. Model tables contains table fields. If you are lucky, you'll find the FK constraints coded into the model tables.